# Get remote address/IP - C Berkeley Sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address, berkeley-sockets

If I have a socket file descriptor connected (either by connect or by bind), type `SOCK_STREAM`, is it possible to get the remote address / IP address?

I need to do this within a function where I don't have any other data than the socket file descriptor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getpeername`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpeername.html)

Answer (score 0):

See the `getpeername()` system call.

Comment: Please add more details.