# C socket get IP address from filedescriptor returned from accept

Tags: c, sockets, unix, fork, file-descriptor

**I know this question seems typical** and multiple times answered but I think if you read the details it is not so common (I did not find it).

The point is that I am developing a **unix service in c that opens a socket** and waits for connections, when I have a connection I **create a new process to treat it**, so there can be **multiple connections opened at the same time**.

```
int newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, (socklen_t*)&clientaddr_size);
```

Later on (**after and inside some other methods** and code) **the child process** save the connection information to the BBDD and I need also, **in that precise moment**, to **get the IP address** that opened that connection being treated.

As there can be **multiple connections at the same time** and the **variable `struct sockaddr_in clientaddr`** that I pass to the accept method is **shared for all the process** I am not sure that later on is a good idea to get the IP address information from that way because then **I could get the IP address from another connection opened**.

I would like to be able to **access the IP address from the file descriptor `int newfd` that I get from the accept method** (the returned integer). Is it possible? Or I misunderstood the file descriptor function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the ip address of the accepted in-bound socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401942/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-accepted-in-bound-socket)

Comment: Thanks @alk I see is so similar, although (for sure because of my english), I didn't need the bind address, I need the client address. Now I have seen the way is similar but with the getpeername() method :)

Comment: Ahok, I see. So you might like to add an answer to you own question, and even accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get remote address/IP - C Berkeley Sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770127/get-remote-address-ip-c-berkeley-sockets)

Comment: Ok. This one yes @JosephQuinsey, equal and and simpler.. Sorry I didn't find it before...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to @alk and @rileyberton I found the correct method to use, the [getpeername](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html):

```
int sockfd;

void main(void) {
    //[...]
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    socklen_t clientaddr_size = sizeof(clientaddr);
    int newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clientaddr_size);
    //fork() and other code
    foo(newfd);
    //[...]
}
void foo(int newfd) {
    //[...]
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int res = getpeername(newfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addr_size);
    char *clientip = new char[20];
    strcpy(clientip, inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
    //[...]
}
```

So now in a different process I can get the IP address (in the "string" `clientip`) of the client that originated the connection only carrying the file descriptor `newfd` obtained with the accept method.

Comment: Do not declare `addr_size` as `int`, but as `socklen_t`. Casting the `int*` to `socklen_t*` in the call to `getpeername()` hides possible issues in case `socklen_t` would be of different size then `int`. Same for the call to `accept()`.

Comment: Done! and also I changed it in the call to accept() method. Thank you very much for the suggestion:)

Answer (score 3):

You would use `getsockname()` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/getsockname) to get the IP of the bound socket.

Also answered before, here: [C - Public IP from file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583052/c-public-ip-from-file-descriptor)

Comment: Thanks @rileyberton, the correct method it worked for me is getpeername() (http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpeername)
I can see is so similar the post but a little bit confusing the question with so much talk between the processes :P

Comment: The IP address of the bound socket is not what he asked for. Read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Statefull connection is uniquely identified by two end points Peer(address:port)<=>My(address:port). Both getpeername() and getsockname() are needed to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Found this helpful [example](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/getpeernameman.html)

This is how I did it

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    socklen_t len; 


    char sendBuff[1025];

    time_t ticks; 

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 

    while(1)
    {
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

        ticks = time(NULL);
        snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
        printf("%d \n",connfd);
        
        getpeername(connfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &len );
        printf("Peer connected %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));

        write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

        close(connfd);
        sleep(1);
     }
}
```